# How to send data enter two interface with JavaFX

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a little problem in my application " Note Taking application". it's when I select an item from a tableView with JavaFX and I click the Edit button. I didn't know how to send this information to a new interface to edit... and thanks.

Here is a piece of code that I realized.. the problem is in the button Edit.... I don't know how to keep the item selected from table view to initialize the TextField and TextArea... I have done to recuperate data from the table view to the TextField and TextArea with this: textField. setText (tableView. getSelectionModel (). getSelectedItem ()); but it never works.

Here is the code that i realized to NewNoteButton and to editButton:

```
@FXML
  public void handleEdit() {
    if (tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() != -1) {
        main.InterfaceEditStart(new Stage());
        main.hideInterfaceWindow();
    }


}

@FXML
public void handleNewNote() {

    main.InterfaceEditStart(new Stage());
    main.hideInterfaceWindow();

}
```

}

Comment: Do you have any code? You need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want any useful answers.

Comment: You ***didn't*** know? Does that mean you know now? Why are you asking then? Furthermore *send[ing] information to a new interface to edit* could mean many things. You need to be more precise. Also what exactly is the problem? Sending the information? Retrieving the information from the `TableView`? Something else?

Comment: Hey Guys I'm not perfect at English.but i try to explain more my problem and i hope we find the solution.